# Sum of normally distibuted random variables?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I feel terribly confused over this.

If:

X~N(μx,σx^2)

Y~N(μy,σy^2)

both independent random variables

Z=X+Y

Z~N(μx+μy,σx^2+σy^2)

Then why:

Xi~N(μi,σi^2)

i=1, 2, ..., n

X1, X2, ..., Xn are independent random variables

Y=c1X1+c2X2+...+cnXn

E(Y)=c1μ1+c2μ2+...+cnμn

V=(c1^2)σ1^2+(c2^2)σ2^2+...+(cn^2)σn^2

In the first case, imagine if X=Y:

Z=X+X

Z=2X

Z~N(2μx,2(σx^2))

But by the second one:

Z=2X

Z~(2μx,2^2*(σx^2))

Why... Is the variance in both cases different?
Or are both properties completely unrelated and I'm doing something dumb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable $X$ is not independent of variable $X$. Thus the correlation coefficient is unequal to zero.

The variance of the sum of two dependent, normally distributed random variables (X,Y) is

$\sigma_{X+Y}^2=\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2+2\rho \sigma_X\cdot \sigma_Y$

*Setting Y equal to X.*

$\sigma_{X+X}^2=\sigma_X^2+\sigma_X^2+2\rho_X \cdot \sigma_X\cdot \sigma_X$

Note, that $\rho_X=Corr(X,X)=1$

$\sigma_{X+X}^2=\sigma_X^2+\sigma_X^2+2\cdot 1 \cdot \sigma_X\cdot \sigma_X=4\sigma_X^2$